# problem with bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, bundle

I try command `bundle install --local`
but it show issue:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/bundle: /usr/local/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

please help me.

Comment: please try: `which ruby` and `which bundle` and share the output

Comment: which ruby: /usr/bin/ruby. which bundle: /usr/local/bin/bundle

Comment: you have a ruby on /usr/local/bin/ruby ? You use rvm ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you need to export the path of ruby and bundle in your .bashrc (linux).

Open your `.bashrc` and add this line:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/"
```

It should work.

Comment: yeah. I sloved it by : ln -s  /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby. Thanks for your sugguest

Comment: I prefer /usr/local/bin before /usr/bin. That way your personal bins run in preference to the system bins.

Answer (score 33):

The solution that worked for me was entirely different, perhaps because I've been inconsistent about using RVM or not.

I used 'which bundler' to find out where bundler was being launched, it was from /usr/bin/bundler.  Noticing that /usr/bin/bundler began with a location and version of ruby that did not exist on my system any more, I did

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler
```

Checking 'which bundler' again confirmed that bundler was now installed within a .rvm environment instead of /usr/bin/bundler, and now references the correct version of ruby; so bundle install now works for my rails project.

Answer (score 6):

The `bundle` executable is provided by the `bundler` gem. If you are using `rvm` then seeing `which bundle` in `/usr/local/bin/bundle` indicates a problem, because use of `rvm` means gems like `bundler` are installed under your home directory, usually in `~/.rvm/gems/...`.

```
# Symptoms of a broken bundler installation:-

# Cannot start Rails...
$ bin/rails s
/Users/rogermarlow/project/config/boot.rb:9:in 'rescue in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant Bundler (NameError)

# bundle not working...
$ bundle install
zsh: /usr/local/bin/bundle: bad interpreter: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin: no such file or directory
#    ^----- that path does not look right, rvm does not put gems there
$ which bundle
/usr/local/bin/bundle
# ^--- I want bundle from something under ~/.rvm/gems

# First check rvm is in effect:
$ rvm reload
RVM reloaded!
$ which ruby
/Users/rogermarlow/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby
# ^--looks good, it is an rvm path, not /usr/local/bin/...

# Now fix bundler
$ gem uninstall bundler    # just in case
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.16.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.16.1
1 gem installed
$ which bundle
/Users/rogermarlow/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4@project/bin/bundle
$ ^--- that is better, bundle is on a path controlled by rvm

# bundle now working
$ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/..........
*snip*

# rails now working
$ bin/rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
*snip*
```

Comment: Thanks Roger.  Following your steps solved a similar problem for me

Answer (score 4):

On my side, I am using rbenv.
When I checked the /usr/local/bin/bundle, it shows it is using the older ruby, thus causing the problem.

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1
```

by changing it to point to proper ruby fix the problem

```
#!/home/user/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

For newly created gem-set gem bundler is missing for me,

Before bundler install path for it, /usr/local/bin/bundler

Installed bundler to resolve issue.

```
gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

Bundler path changes to, /home/root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1@drag-drop-list/bin/bundler

Answer (score -1):

Encountering this same problem,
I found bundler installation in `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1;`
Then i fixed the error by creating a symbolic link like this:

`ln -s /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1/ 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.1`

I did this because I needed this version of ruby.