# zsh: /usr/bin/bundle: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/ruby: no such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am pretty new to ruby and rails development, And I am working on *linux subsystem for windows*. I have been getting the above mentioned error. Here's what all I have done:

- reinstalled rvm
- added `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin/:/usr/share/rvm/bin:/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin"` the path in `.zshrc` file

but the problem is still persisting. another thing I know is rvm is installed in `/usr/share/` directory

I have also referred this link:
[problem with bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958092/problem-with-bundle)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Sometimes, deleting the `$GEM_HOME` directory fixes this kind of issues.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you to run `which bundle` command. The path it returns contains a ruby version. I'm almost sure that you won't have this ruby version on your local machine. Check that by running `rvm list`. To solve the problem try either installing the version of ruby or reinstalling `bundler` using sudo and gem- `sudo gem uninstall bundler` - > `sudo gem install bundler`.

**NOTE:** your ruby version has to be the same with the one in the Gemfile.

Comment: [**Never install dependencies with `sudo`!**](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/wiki/Best-Practice%3A--Never-install-gems-with-sudo)