# Middleman command not found/ Bundler not working

Tags: ruby, bundle, bundler, middleman

I'm trying to install middleman. I installed the gem and can see it in my gem list. However, if I enter `middleman -v` I get the message `middleman: command not found`.

I tried installing bundler to run middleman with a Gemfile in the project directory using `bundle exec middleman`. But when I try to run bundle I get the following error:
`bash: /usr/bin/bundle: /usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

I'm running ruby v. 2.6 and installed middleman v.4.3.5 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Any help would be very much appreciated; I've wasted half a day trying to solve this and I'm still on high waters!

Comment: Include the output from `gem install middleman` and `which middleman`. Also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3958092/3784008) and apply the fixes from the answers first.

Answer (score 0):

`which ruby` gives me `/snap/bin/ruby` and my path variable is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/share/rvm/bin`. The problem is that ruby is in the snap folder.
I just uninstalled the ruby snap (and snaps in general) and installed "normal" Ruby, which had the correct path (`usr/bin/ruby`). The middleman installation then worked fine.